# How to translate column names to variables in Java program?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose you have thousands of rows of data coming from a table

```
    Index      | First_name       |    Last_name 
=====================================================
    1          |  John            |     Doe
    2          |  Jane            |     Doe
```

The task is to represent each individual row of this table in some bean. For example, it would be nice to have

```
private int index;
private String firstName
private String lastName
```

Unfortunately **number of columns and column names is not known** and beans can't be created ahead of harvesting data

**I therefore can not hardcode variables name to expect a `firstName`. I don't know how many variables i need and the type of these variables.**

Is there a way i can represent a row in a table as part of a bean where variable names are the same as column names?

The idea here is that i ultimately would have to compare 'n' of these beans and would like to intelligently report on the differences

I suppose i can have

```
Set<String> columnNames
List<Object> columnData
```

And then match by index, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Are you fetching the data via JDBC?

Comment: More typically in Java, column names like `First_name` are translated to their Java equivalent of `firstName`.

Comment: @mac: in one of the comments you mentioned that you don't know the table name either, but this is not reflected in your question. Do you know the table name?

Comment: @home. Yes, table name is known. Basically it will be a table of some arbitrary data. We won't know what it is until we look there. I can not hardcode expected column names, number of columns, type of data stored in there etc

Comment: @toto. Let me try and clarify. I need a Java bean being able to represent a row of data in the table, where number of columns is unknown and names of columns are unknown. I then need to be able to refer to data element retrieved from a given column (preferably by name of the column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to represent your data would be a `Map<String, Object>` for each line, instead of a custom Bean class which you would have to create first ... and which you can't really use afterwards, without knowing which properties (e.g. get/set pairs) it has.

Reflection can't create classes (or interfaces), though you could use some bytecode manipulation library, or generate Java source code and pass it to the compiler. (But still, how would you use the class afterwards? Still only with reflection.)

Comment: What would the String/ Object represent in the above example?

Comment: The strings would be the column names, the objects the values (e.g. an `Integer` for the index column, a String for the other ones).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDBC, you could use [ResultSet.getMetaData()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to get additional information about the columns being returned in your resultset, their names and their types.

Comment: Correct. And how to i "create a variable with the same name as a column name"?

Comment: @mac -- Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/LazyDynaBean.html .. You could instantiate a LazyDynaBean with properties and values ( sort of like a Map )

Answer (score 0):

Well, in theory you could use a bytecode manipulation library (like BCEL: http://bcel.sourceforge.net/) to create classes on the fly, then load them into your JVM.

However, this is unlikely to be worth the effort. Perhaps you should ask yourself why the database columns have to be fields in a Java class. What are you planning to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on reading the column names and types (assume connection is a `java.sql.Connection`):

```
    DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rsColumns = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "tablename", null);
    while (rsColumns.next()) 
    {
      String columnName = rsColumns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
      String columnType = rsColumns.getString("TYPE_NAME");

      // Do your magic

    }
```

Comment: This would be fine, but i don't know what the name of the table is. I therefore can't intelligently name my variable. I don't know how many i need for instance